# How to pass a table reference/name as a parameter to a method?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

Let's say I have in my method this call:

```
fieldNum(_myTableName, HouseNumber);
```

How do I pass the _myTableName from another method? What type should this parameter have? I tried:

when _myTableName is int
fieldNum(tableId2Name(_myTableName), HouseNumber);

But it doesn't allow this thing, then tried passing _myTableName as string, which I would logically also expect to work, but doesn't aswell, how do I pass the parameter to be able to use it in fieldNum call? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, as the `fieldNum` built-in function is a compile-time function, which means you must pass a valid table and field name (not a string) as parameters.

There are other functions that operates on strings (`fieldName2Id`) or integers (fieldId2Name). These functions are evaluated at run-time.

Best practice is to pass table or field references as integers (`TableId` and `FieldId` extended data types respectively). If you intend to store the values in a non-temporary database table consider storing the names instead.